# Does locally compact and paracompact imply $X\setminus E$ is contained in a countable union of compact sets, when $E$ has finite (Baire) measure?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, proof-explanation, compactness, paracompactness

I have been trying to get an understandable, self-contained proof about the regularity of Baire measures in locally compact spaces. Failing to follow Royden's proof - which required the lemma I asked about in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4395995/815585) question - I found [this](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2039060) article on JSTOR which was promising and slightly more general.

In all that follows, the Baire $\sigma$-algebra is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra in which the compactly supported continuous real valued functions on a set are measurable. However, since I am asking only about locally compact Hausdorff (LCH) spaces, we may just consider the Baire algebra as that generated by all compact $G_\delta$ sets - $G_\delta$ meaning the countable intersection of open sets - as it can be shown they are equal in this instance. A Baire measure is a measure on the Baire algebra which is finite on all the compact sets.

The JSTOR article proves (at first) that:

> For any paracompact LCH space $X$ and a Baire measure $\mu$ thereon, $\mu$ is outer regular.

Reading their proof, I fall at the first hurdle:

> Let $E$ be a Baire subset of $X$ [...] outer regularity is well-known if $E$ is $G_\delta$ or if $\mu(E)=\infty$. Hence we may assume that $\mu(E)\lt\infty$ **and that $A:=X\setminus E$ is $\sigma$-bounded**.

$\sigma$-bounded means "contained in a countable union of compact sets". Naturally if $X$ is itself $\sigma$-compact this is obvious, but why should $A$ be $\sigma$-bounded in general?

I tried to reach a contradiction - if $A$ is not $\sigma$-bounded, then $\mu(E)=\infty$, or perhaps that if $A$ is not $\sigma$-bounded, $E$ is evidently outer regular.

$A$ not being $\sigma$-bounded implies that any countable union of compact sets will not cover $A$. In particular, for any collection of compact sets $\{K_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ for which $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}K_n\subseteq A$, $E\subseteq\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}(X\setminus K_n)$. This does not seem to imply outer regularity however, since each of the sets $X\setminus K_n$ may well have infinite $\mu$-measure and we don't have equality, so I'm not sure if we can say that $E$ is $G_\delta$, only that $E$ is a subset of a $G_\delta$ set.

What is the obvious "without loss of generality" principle that I am missing?

Comment: In fact they say it’s well-known for $E\in \mathcal{R}_a$; they even mention that right at the beginning of the paper quoting Halmos.

Answer (score 1):

Lemma 5 in Royden real analysis (3rd ed) on page 333 says: if $E$ is Baire then $E$ or $X\setminus E$ is $\sigma$-bounded. If $E$ were $E$ would be in $\mathcal{R}_a$ (lemma 6 same page) and that case was already discarded as known (with an appeal to an earlier edition of Royden).

FYI the paper is freely available [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1972-036-01/S0002-9939-1972-0316660-2/S0002-9939-1972-0316660-2.pdf) (no JSTOR needed). Free archives FTW!

Comment: I am on the $4$ edition, and sadly there is no mention of this that I've seen (I've read pretty much every page before this - this is chapter $20$ I am on, page $480$). Side-note: are compact Baire sets outer-regular? I know that they form a regular subspace, but are they themselves regular in the parent space?

Comment: @FShrike yes compact Baire sets are $G_\delta$ so quite trivially outer regular.

Comment: compact + Baire implies $G_\delta$? This has not been mentioned in the text thus far. Yes, the compact $G_\delta$ sets generate the Baire algebra but in the converse this is not clear in the absence of a metric. Am I supposed to show that if it is not $G_\delta$, it cannot be Baire?

Comment: @FShrike yes it’s in both Royden and Halmos. The proofs are not from contradiction but rather clever. Look them up. Your library should have them.

Comment: Well, thank you for noting Halmos’ text. I found an online copy and was able to get the necessary details from that. Amusingly, in my failed attempts to google a self-contained answer online, the top searches were always comments from you yourself on “ask a topologist”!

Comment: @FShrike that forum is long closed now. But still searchable. ASCII only, no mathjax or markup support like here.